# Debug Go code in VS Code by running buffalo command in terminal

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, buffalo

I want to debug the GO code in VS code. I basically want to attach the go project which is open in VS code to the terminal and then run some "buffalo task" command in terminal, which then directs me to my breakpoints in VS code.
Please help me and give some suggestions n how can I do that.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This should help explain how to debug Golang programs in VS Code,
https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md